# Different customer portfolio, shipping and payment methods for each store view?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, payment

Let me explain better: we will release another brand however the company group is the same. The point is that I've created a new store view because the catalog, categories and most of the store attributes will be shared with each other, and I didn't see options neither to set different payment and/or shipping methods nor to see customers separated by store view.

Is it possible having differente payment, shipping and customers for each store view?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible.
The customer accounts and payment & shipping methods can be enabled/disabled at website level.
So if you want them different, you can create a new website, assign the store view you have to that website and then you will be able to separate them. from system->configuration. Customer section for customers and payment section for payment methods

Comment: Even if the store view is currently associated to another website, can we associate it to a new website and use the layout we already applied for it?

Comment: I think so. I haven't tried it, but it should be possible. Just edit the store view and see if you can change the website.

Comment: I've tested creating a new store (not a website) and, yes, I could associate a store view to a new store. I will make a test by creating a new website and next I will try to associate a store view for that website.